# Mysql Database error connection

Tags: php, mysql

Might sound obvious but my database isn't connecting to my phpmyadmin.

is there something I did wrong? I'm using mamp as a backend server for php use.

```
 <?php
    //
    require('database.php');
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','blurt');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['Register'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
         //echo $query;
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if($result){
            $smsg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }else{
            $fmsg ="User Registration Failed";
        }
    }

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'blurt');
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    } $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'blurt');
    if (!$select_db) {
        die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: show where you establish the database connection

Comment: post it in your question. do not put code in comments

Comment: (To create a *code block*, just "use the button", the keyboard-short-cut or precede each line with four additional blanks - don't enclose it in additional `\`\`` backticks.)

Comment: what is the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by seeing your question it is looks like you are registering the connection after the query..

please try to change the order..

$connection have to be created before using that..

some this like below:

```
// Step -1
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'blurt');
if (!$connection) {
die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
} $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'blurt');
if (!$select_db) {
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}

//Step-2
$query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
 //echo $query;
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if($result){
    $smsg = "User Created Successfully.";
}else{
    $fmsg ="User Registration Failed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
} 

$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname');
if (!$select_db) {
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
 $query = "INSERT INTO `user` ('$username', '$email', '$password') VALUES ('username', 'email', 'password')";
     //echo $query;
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if($result){
        $smsg = "User Created Successfully.";
    }else{
        $fmsg ="User Registration Failed";
    }
```

Comment: please change dbname to your database name

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very sample

here : http://curs.io/KN97HAOB